# Dockerfile - Unable to copy all files from one folder to another within container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following in my Dockerfile - I'm trying to copy all the contents of the source folder (a folder of JARs) to the destination but it simply doesn't work.

Any ideas?

`RUN cp -R /tmp/usr/kafka-connect/. /etc/kafka-connect/jars/`

I've also tried

`RUN cp -R /tmp/usr/kafka-connect/ /etc/kafka-connect/jars/`

and

`RUN cp -a /tmp/usr/kafka-connect/. /etc/kafka-connect/jars/`

with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What ends up in the destination directory? What does the `docker build` output for these steps contain? Does `cp -v` give you any clues?

Comment: Nothing ends up in the destination director

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `COPY` instead of `RUN`.

```
COPY /tmp/usr/kafka-connect /etc/kafka-connect/jars
```

You can also use the `WORKDIR` instruction and then the destination path can be relative to `WORKDIR`.

The source path can be relative to the build context.